# Passing child class as a parameter in a constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am new to c++ and i'm trying to create an instance of Player which takes an argument of RoleCard. I would like to be able to pass a MedicCard which inherits RoleCard in the Driver.cpp. However, I can't seem to find the proper way to do this. My goal would be to be able to dynamically change the variable roleCard to create new Player instances.

Driver.cpp

```
RoleCard roleCard;
MedicCard medicCard;    
roleCard = medicCard;

Player demoPlayer(roleCard);
```

Player.h

```
#pragma once
#include "RoleCard.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Player
    {
    public:
        Player();
        Player( RoleCard rolecard );            
    };
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include<string>

using namespace std;

Player::Player()
{
}

Player::Player(RoleCard roleCard)
{    
}
```

RoleCard.h

```
#pragma once

class RoleCard
{
public:
    RoleCard();
};

class MedicCard: public RoleCard
{
public:
    MedicCard();
};
```

RoleCard.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "RoleCard.h"

using namespace std;

RoleCard::RoleCard()
{    
}
MedicCard::MedicCard()
{    
}
```

Comment: What is the error in particular? Please add the error text verbatim to your question ([edit]).

Comment: That's not your error. Copy/paste the raw output from the compiler. If that _is_ your error, the code you're showing us isn't the code you're trying to compile; please provide a [mcve] and show us the output _that_ gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign object of derived class to an object of base class like this

```
RoleCard roleCard;
MedicCard medicCard;    
roleCard = medicCard;
```

you [discard all of the data](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-slicing-in-c/) in derived class (otherwise known as slicing). 
If you want polymorphic behavior, use references or pointers to a base class:

```
Player(RoleCard& rolecard);
...
MedicCard medicCard;
Player demoPlayer(medicCard);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer and great link